# Окно PyQt5 просто закрывается с кодом 1

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Пробую рисовать в PyQt5 , но вечно появляется окно и сразу исчезает, если я правильно успеваю разглядеть , то ничего там в нём не нарисовано + возращает код завершения 1

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.resize(300,300)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        black = QtCore.Qt.black
        red = QtGui.QColor('#f00')
        painter.setPen(black)
        painter.setBrush((QtGui.QBrush(red)))
        painter.drawText(3, 3, 294, 294)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('Класс QColor')
    window.show()
    print(QtGui.QColor.colorNames())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы указали не все аргументы в вызове метода `drawText`. Из документации:

> void QPainter::drawText(int x, int y, int width, int height, int flags, const QString &text, QRect *boundingRect = Q_NULLPTR)

Вы указали только позицию (`x, y`) и размеры (`width, height`), поэтому программа завершается с ошибкой:

> painter.drawText(3, 3, 294, 294)
>
> **TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:**
> drawText(self, Union[QPointF, QPoint], str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
> drawText(self, QRectF, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
> drawText(self, int, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
> drawText(self, QRectF, str, option: QTextOption = QTextOption()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
> drawText(self, QPoint, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
> drawText(self, int, int, int, int, str): not enough arguments
> drawText(self, int, int, str): 3 has unexpected type 'int'

Необходимо передать еще два аргумента: `int flags` и `const QString &text`.
Флаги задают форматирование и выравнивание текста - конкретнее можно посмотреть в документации. Можно использовать вызов без флага (0). И, конечно, надо передать саму строку, которую хотите вывести.

**Пример:**

```
painter.drawText(3, 3, 294, 294, 0, 'Test line without flags')
```